# Dispatcher servlet is not able to map my request.I am using spring 2

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, web.xml

I have a simple spring application. The basic implementation is, my app will accept the url's .I have a configuration for dispatcher servlet in web.xml. From there the request is handed over to url handler mapping which maps the url to a controller which is configured in application-web.xml. Normal scenarios it works fine

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:application-web.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

**application-context.xml**

```
    <bean id="urlMapping"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">

    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <!-- Integration: URL Mapping for Page controllers START -->
            <!-- DEFAULT URL MAPPING -->
            <prop key="/*">pasController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

</bean>
```

But for one particular url I am facing issue. 
localhost:7001//..................../etc1/passwd

For the above mentioned url, dispatcher servlet is not able to map it to the controller, so because of this request stuck in weblogic level and thread will be stuck.I mean during the mapping process it is getting stuck, container is not able to know what to do.It is not even reaching the application context level.

How to overgo through this situation?Is there any way to play with the above kind of url's. I tried with both spring 2 ang spring3 web mvc jars.

Comment: Are you trying to map all requests to `pasController`?

Comment: `classpath:application-web.xml` but `application-context.xml`.

Comment: its a typo error....xml name is fine...